# Processes getting exited with exit code 145 in parallel processing(unix)

Tags: shell, parallel-processing, signals, ksh, child-process

I am using the following code snippet for handling the child processes :

```
res=0
handle_chld() {
local tmp=()
for i in ${!pids[@]}; do
     if [ ! -d /proc/${pids[i]} ]; then
     wait ${pids[i]}
     ret_cd=`echo $?`
            if [ $ret_cd -ne 0 ]; then
            res=$ret_cd
            fi
            echo "Stopped ${pids[i]}; exit code: $ret_cd" >> ${logfile}
            STATUS+=($ret_cd)

            unset pids[i]
     fi
     done
}
set -o monitor
trap "handle_chld" CHLD
```

Then we are calling all the 9 scripts which loads the respective data into the tables:

```
sh filepath/script1.sh params
tmp=$!
pids+=($tmp)
.
.
.
sh filepath/script9.sh params
tmp=$!
pids+=($tmp)
```

We wait for the process until it is complete:

```
while [ ${#pids[@]} -gt 0 ]; do
echo "WAITING FOR: ${pids[@]}" >> ${logfile}
sleep 1;
done
```

Here is the log :

```
WAITING FOR: 3034365 3034367 3034368 3034369 3034370 3034374 3034379 3034393 3034401
WAITING FOR: 3034365 3034367 3034368 3034369 3034370 3034374 3034379 3034393 3034401
WAITING FOR: 3034365 3034367 3034368 3034369 3034370 3034374 3034379 3034393 3034401
WAITING FOR: 3034365 3034367 3034368 3034369 3034370 3034374 3034379 3034393 3034401
WAITING FOR: 3034365 3034367 3034368 3034369 3034370 3034374 3034379 3034393 3034401
Stopped 3034370; exit code: 0
WAITING FOR: 3034365 3034367 3034368 3034369 3034374 3034379 3034393 3034401
Stopped 3034365; exit code: 145
Stopped 3034369; exit code: 145
Stopped 3034374; exit code: 145
WAITING FOR: 3034367 3034368 3034379 3034393 3034401
Stopped 3034393; exit code: 145
Stopped 3034401; exit code: 145
WAITING FOR: 3034367 3034368 3034379
Stopped 3034368; exit code: 145
Stopped 3034367; exit code: 145
WAITING FOR: 3034379
WAITING FOR: 3034379
WAITING FOR: 3034379
WAITING FOR: 3034379
WAITING FOR: 3034379
WAITING FOR: 3034379
WAITING FOR: 3034379
WAITING FOR: 3034379
WAITING FOR: 3034379
Stopped 3034379; exit code: 145
```

All this gets executed successfully and data is also loaded into the tables but only the script1 exits with error code 0 and rest of the 8 scripts exits with error code 145. I am not able to find any references and workaround for this. What can I try next?
Additional Details:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.6 (Ootpa)
$ uname -a
Linux srvr51 4.18.0-372.16.1.el8_6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 28 
03:02:21 EDT 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ ksh --version
version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01
$ echo $KSH_VERSION
Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01
$ uname -mrs
Linux 4.18.0-372.16.1.el8_6.x86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify exactly which shell(s) you are using. If using Ksh, please report the exact version of Korn shell, and the operating-system on which it is running.  Without seeing the debugging output of the `sh ...script.sh`, we cannot know the exit-code of the last command in the subscripts. If you are starting multiple jobs in parallel, then I would expect you to use the `wait` command without arguments so that it will wait for any of the subscripts to complete, and I would expect to get the exit code in korn-shell via `ret_cd=$?` (not to exec echo to get it).

Comment: @mao I have edited the question. Shell type is ksh and OS is RHEL 8.6. The first process exits with an exit code of 0 and the rest with 145. The log of the first process and other processes are same and apart from that all the scripts are working as expected.

Comment: Updates noted. Your parent script is KSH, but you invoke bourne-shell for the subscripts.  It's unclear where the parallelism happens, as you are not invoking the subscripts with the ampersand.  Consider creating a minimal reproducible set of scripts to demo the problem, and consider responding to my other remarks.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53403220/bash-why-wait-returns-prematurely-with-code-145

Comment: @mao, Sorry I forgot adding ampersand here but it is there in the original script. OK, I'll add the wait command instead of the while loop doing the work and will let you know about the results. One extra point to note is, we have recently migrated from grid server to standalone server. In the grid server(that was again a Ksh type), the same scripts were running fine. But here in standalone, it is creating the issue. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I used the wait command but again it is 145. I checked the tagged question but I dint find any solution to have the scripts' exit code as 0 instead of 145. I tried the ret-cd=$? also but the same result.

Comment: As previously requested, consider creating a minimal complete reproducible set of scripts to demonstrate the problem .  See  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  We cannot do debugging for you as we do not have your code, and we do not have access to your system/message-logs etc. Most likely a child task has some signal handling that is contributing to the symptom.